# Wiring a double oven on a wall opposing the wiring?

Tags: wiring, oven

I upgraded from a single to a double oven and need to move it to the other side of the kitchen. Is it safe to run a 220V extension cord from the wiring to the oven under the flooring? If not what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not safe nor to code. Extension cords cannot be concealed. A new circuit should be run to the new location and the old circuit decommissioned and/or removed.  Depending on if the oven is hardwired or corded will dictate how it should be terminated (either a plug or an electrical box).

It sounds like you are unfamiliar with this, so the "best" way is to contact a licensed electrician to completely this.